# $\frac{\int_0^1x^n\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\int_0^1x^{n-2}\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

Tags: calculus

I want to compute the following ratio:
$$\frac{\int_0^1x^n\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\int_0^1x^{n-2}\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

As I found from wolframe it is $\frac{n-1}{n+2}$. I am trying to solve the integral using the following substitution:

$$f(x) = x^{n-2}\sqrt{1-x^2}$$
$$\frac{\int_0^1x^2f(x)}{\int_0^1f(x)}$$

But I am sticking here.

Comment: Why not to use $x=\sin(t)$ and reduction formulae ?

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2255782, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2254714

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x=\sin y $$
$$\implies \frac{\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\sin^n y\cos^2y\ dy }{\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\sin^{n-2}y\cos^2y\ dy}$$

Use the reduction rule or Wallis formula for cosine/ sine rule.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the integral $$\int_0^1 x^{n} \sqrt{1-x^2} dx$$ is a Beta function so you can easily count it.

Otherwise, if you don't know the Beta function so mark $x=\sin{t}$ and again you'll easily count the integral.

Comment: By count you mean evaluate?